# Does Swift is used for image processing, or i need to integrate/run python code in IOS?

Tags: computer-vision, python

I've  made two simple photo effects with python while i am learning image processing. I want these effects to get inside IOS app, and then to  try to use them  on an image taken from a camera. But i am not sure how to integrate a Python code/script  inside IOS. I don't want to write Python code inside IOS, i want to run it from other place if that possible.

Or, should i re-write the code with swift? But i don't want to my app to get messy, so i was looking to call Python scripts via REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can rewrite your DSP code in Swift, and the code will possibly run lots faster if you do convert from Python.  For certain common DSP operations, Swift code can call vDSP functions, which are included inside the iOS Accelerate framework.

Sending an entire image to a server for processing is also possible, but that incurs server infrastructure costs, bandwidth costs, network latency, and privacy concerns, in addition to any processing.